# Communicating with IdentityServer4 with Owin Startup class in Asp.Net WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, owin, identityserver4

I am trying to get currently logged in User in IdentityServer4 from my Asp.Net webforms application.

Since there is no example for WebForms project, I am using example from IdentityServer3 provided in [GitHub repo of IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/WebFormsClient/Startup.cs)

Here is the `client config in IdentityServer4` project

```
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "Foo",
            ClientName = "Foo",
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("Secret".Sha256())
            },
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            RequirePkce = false,
            RequireClientSecret = false,
            RequireConsent = false,
            RedirectUris = redirectUris,
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = postLogoutRedirectUris,
            BackChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost/LogOff",
            AllowedCorsOrigins = allowedCorsOrigins,
            AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                "firstName",
                "lastName",
                "emailId",
                "api1"
            }
        }
```

Here is the startup class in Asp.Net webForms project

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        tokenHandler.InboundClaimFilter.Clear();

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            Authority = "https://localhost:44367",
            ClientId = "Foo",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost/callback",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost/LogOff",
            ResponseType = "id_token token",
            Scope = "openid profile emailId",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                {
                    var claims_to_exclude = new[]
                    {
                        "aud", "iss", "nbf", "exp", "nonce", "iat", "at_hash"
                    };

                    var claims_to_keep =
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims.Where(x => false == claims_to_exclude.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();
                    claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken != null)
                    {
                        claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                        var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(EP_Configuration.epIdpUserInfoAccessPoint);
                        var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);
                        var userInfoClaims = userInfoResponse.Claims; // filter sub since we're already getting it from id_token
                        claims_to_keep.AddRange(userInfoClaims);
                    }

                    var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                    ci.AddClaims(claims_to_keep);
                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket(
                        ci, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties
                    );
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                    {
                        var id_token = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token")?.Value;
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = id_token;
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
    }
}
```

A user is loggedIn, in IdentityServer as shown in image below,

[image: 1]

But Currentuser does not seem to be getting any claims and IsAuthenticated is false

```
    void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // now you can fix up you session object from
        // if you use session state (which makes me sad if you do)
        var cp = (ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User;
    }
```

[image]

Any idea how I can make my startup to work and, get currently logged in User in IdentityServer in Asp.Net webforms project from server side.

PS: Looks like WebForm client is not calling IdentityServer at all. Log file of identity server does not contain any update when I run the client application

Here is the log file of IdentityServer

```
2019-06-03 16:36:05.074 +02:00 [INF] Starting IdentityServer4 version 2.3.2.0
2019-06-03 16:36:05.119 +02:00 [INF] You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.
2019-06-03 16:36:05.126 +02:00 [INF] Using the default authentication scheme idsrv for IdentityServer
2019-06-03 16:36:05.126 +02:00 [DBG] Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for authentication
2019-06-03 16:36:05.126 +02:00 [DBG] Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-in
2019-06-03 16:36:05.126 +02:00 [DBG] Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for sign-out
2019-06-03 16:36:05.126 +02:00 [DBG] Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for challenge
2019-06-03 16:36:05.126 +02:00 [DBG] Using idsrv as default ASP.NET Core scheme for forbid
2019-06-03 16:36:05.437 +02:00 [DBG] Login Url: /Account/Login
2019-06-03 16:36:05.438 +02:00 [DBG] Login Return Url Parameter: ReturnUrl
2019-06-03 16:36:05.439 +02:00 [DBG] Logout Url: /Account/Logout
2019-06-03 16:36:05.439 +02:00 [DBG] ConsentUrl Url: /consent
2019-06-03 16:36:05.439 +02:00 [DBG] Consent Return Url Parameter: returnUrl
2019-06-03 16:36:05.439 +02:00 [DBG] Error Url: /home/error
2019-06-03 16:36:05.439 +02:00 [DBG] Error Id Parameter: errorId
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have not secured anything in `web.config` like the following:

```xml
<location path="About">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Or just

```xml
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

to secure the whole app.

You also have to precheck that you have `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll` and all the dependencies in the `bin` folder (but that should be so as you've been able to compile).

Comment: web.config is secured. And Microsoft.Owin.Host.SysteWeb.dll is there in bin

Comment: anyway first it would be good to ensure that your owin startup works at all. you can start with the simplest middleware such as: `app.Use(async (context, next) =>{await next.Invoke();});` and debug or log inside.

Comment: and, as you say: "IsAuthenticated is false", the app can't be secured, otherwise it has to respond: *access denied* (in case when redirect doesn't work).

Comment: If you show your web.config, we could distinguish what's going on with your auth. In system.web everything's configurable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pages are secured via `Web.config`, you can get to your `ClaimsPrincipal` from within any secure page's `Page_Load` method with:

```
ClaimsPrincipal cp = Page.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
claims = cp.Claims.ToList();
```